# Odoo v12 server with custom outgoing email server is not sending emails

Tags: odoo, odoo-12

I have installed Odoo v12 on a server and I have configured an outgoing mail server given by my organization. I have tested the conection and everything seems to be ok. But for some reason the server is not sending the emails.
I have tested the outgoing mail configurations on my local machine and my local odoo is sending the emails successfully, but for some reason that same configuration is not working on a server.

When I go to Settings->Technical->Emails to see the email failed, I see that the "Failure Reason" tab shows the following message
"Error without exception. Probably due do sending an email without computed recipients"
But I checked an the email message has all the recipients. I the next image you will see (message is in Spanish)

[image: Email image]

This is an image of the odoo log

[image: Image of odoo log]

In the next images you can see that the email server is configured

[image: outgoing mail server configuration]

[image: testing conection]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Odoo answered that i should use odoo-mail-server only for transactional emails (orders and invoices)
...and that i should use an external mail-server pour mailing campaigns, to prevent them from reducing the deliverability-score of transactional emails.

I have chosen "Brevo", which does the job so far.